# How to adress method in class

Tags: apex, method, variable, zuora

How do I access the method getDateTime in the following class.
I tried `ZuoraObject zo = new ZuoraObject();` but get the error constructor not defined

```
public class ZuoraObject  {
    private Zuora.zObject xObj;
    private string xObjectType;
    private string xNamespace;
    private Map<String, object> xAttributes;


    public ZuoraObject(string objectType)
    {
        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            xObjectType = objectType;
            xNamespace = 'http://object.api.zuora.com/';
            xAttributes = new Map<String, object>(); 
        }
        else{
            xObj = new Zuora.zObject(objectType);
        }
    }
 public DateTime getDateTime(String fieldName){
        if(String.isBlank(fieldName)){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? `getDateTime()` falls off the end with no explicit return value.

Comment: I assumed this was cut-down code so have ignored various issues such as this :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class has an explicit constructor that takes an object type, so you need to construct the instance passing in an object type:

```
String someObjectType = ...; // Set it somehow. In this case null might be
                             // appropriate but it rather depends on the code
                             // you omitted
ZuoraObject zo = new ZuoraObject(someObjectType);
```

You can then access the getDateTime method, passing in some field name:

```
String someFieldName = ...; // Set to whatever you need
Datetime dt = zo.getDateTime(someFieldName);
```

Note that the getDateTime is an instance method, not a static one, so you do need an instance to call it on.